# Windows 8 System Wide Audio (not per user)

Tags: windows-8, audio

Is it possible to have audio from another logged in user continue to play when I use fast user switching?

Previously I could switch users and audio would continue to play from the locked user.

This was very useful for a HTPC since I could open iTunes on one user and switch to the dedicated media center user and then use the iTunes remote app to play audio (or even ShairPort for AirPlay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. It is by default as a design in Windows 8 when you switch to another user account, the sound will be disabled by default on the current user account, to avoid the conflict.

Hope this helps.